# rxjs with angular 2, keep track and be able to cancel multiple simultaneous server calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to make X number of calls to multiple remote servers and I need to be able to keep track of servers that responded, and ones that did not. As well as be able to cancel all pending calls.

The idea is to loop over a given list of servers array and use `switchMap` to be able to cancel out.

this is the code I got so far:

```
private listenFetchBusinessUser() {         
    this.businessesRequest$ = new Subject();
    this.unsub = this.businessesRequest$
        .map(v=> {
            return v;
        })
        .debounceTime(100)
        .switchMap((values:{servers:Array<string>, dispatch:(value:any)=>any}):any => {
            if (values.servers.length == 0)
                return 'CANCEL_PENDING_NET_CALLS';
            var dispatch = values.dispatch;

            return values.servers.map(i_source => {
                var url:string = `http://${i_source}/WebService/StationService.asmx/getSocketStatusList?i_businessList=123`;
                return this._http.get(url)
                    .map(result => {
                        console.log(result);
                    }).subscribe((res)=> {
                    }, err=> {
                        console.log(err);
                    }, ()=> {
                        console.log();
                    });            
             })

        }).share()
        .subscribe();
}


public fetchBusinessUser(servers:Array<string>) {
   return (dispatch) => {
      this.businessesRequest$.next({servers: servers, dispatch: dispatch});
   };
}
```

so the idea is that I will call fetchBusinessUser with the list of servers and it will use the Subject to push the http calls to through the stream.

but so far I am getting an error of:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)'
>   of undefined

when I try and run through the return `this._http.get(url)`...

I am open for any (better) ideas on how to use rxjs to handle this requirement... basically to call multiple servers, track pending calls and be able to just forcible cancel everything...

Comment: You don't appear to be returning anything in your `switchMap`...

Comment: tx for the comment, yes you right, I fixed it and no more error... TX!! however i do need to add a subscribe at the level of the https calls, and it seems wrong, can't I just get by, by using a single subscribe to the entire call stack? regards and tx